# Actionscript 3 null object reference combobox

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox

I put a combo box inside of a movie clip, I put data into it through code. When I click it, I get a null object reference.  Below is the output.

I can create a combo box and it works just fine in a test fla file. The fla file I'm working in is big, with a lot of assets and movie clips, so I'm not sure where the problem is, just hoping someone will have a hint. Thanks

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at fl.containers::BaseScrollPane/drawBackground()
at fl.controls::List/draw()
at fl.core::UIComponent/drawNow()
at fl.controls::List/scrollToIndex()
at fl.controls::SelectableList/scrollToSelected()
at fl.controls::ComboBox/open()
at fl.controls::ComboBox/onToggleListVisibility()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the objects correctly. If missed some instantiation then this type of problem occurs